# Dimension of the space of all $m\times n$ matrices over $F$

Tags: vector-spaces

Prove that the space of all $m*n$ matrices over the field  $F$ has dimension $mn$, by exhibiting a basis for this space. 
I know that it is too easy to prove but cannot remember any basis for this space.
please help me.

Comment: Basically the same you use for vectors.

Comment: I can't understand your hint sir.@G.Sassatelli

Answer (score 0):

If $m=n=2$, then the matrices
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
form a basis.

Try proving this, and then extend to general $m,n$.

Comment: If $m=n$ i.e if the argument is of square matrix then it can obviously done upto $n*n$. But how i  will approach when $m≠n$?

Comment: @abcdmath The same thing. For example, if $m=2$ and $n=1$, then
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix} \quad\text{and}\quad
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
form a basis.

Comment: thank you @John Griffin